# Change accessible fields BeforeSave using CRUD plugin [CakePHP 3]

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, crud

I'm trying to change the accessible fields beforeSave if the user is a manager

```
$this->Crud->on('beforeSave', function(Event $event) {
    if($this->Auth->user('role') == 'Manager')
    {
        $this->Crud->action()->saveOptions(['accessibleFields' => ['verified' => true]]);
    }
});
```

But it doesn't seems to work, why?

Edit: To clarify, I'm trying to do a PUT HTTP Request through my API and change the value of the field "verified". I can change every fields I have set to accessible in my entity.php just fine, but when I am trying to change the "verified" field after the beforeSave above, I don't see any change in the object, because it seems to not set the field has accessible.

Edit 2: From the official documentation of the [CRUD](http://crud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/actions/edit.html#saveoptions) plugin, I've tried doing 
`$this->Crud->action()->saveOptions(['atomic' => false]);` but couldn't get it to work. I've send an [issue](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud/issues/491) on the crud plugin GitHub page hopefully will get more replies there.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? What are you seeing instead of your desired behaviour?

Comment: It won't change the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution with my issue on GitHub

```
$this->Crud->action()->config('saveOptions.accessibleFields', ['verified' => true])
```

I have to use this in my controller's method, I do not need the beforeSave. My code looks like this

```
if($this->Auth->user('role') == 'Manager') $this->Crud->action()->config('saveOptions.accessibleFields', ['verified' => true]);
$this->Crud->on('afterSave', function(Event $event) {
    /*[...]*/
}
```